How would I pass an array argument into this SQLite query?
I'm using the promised-sqlite3 library here for queries.
I need to match the string value of the field video against any one of the strings in the array videos.
At first I tried:
  await db.all('SELECT video, offset, watched FROM watched WHERE user = ? AND video IN ?',
    username(req), videos);

...but that syntax isn't accepted. Then I tried:
  await db.all('SELECT video, offset, watched FROM watched WHERE user = ? AND video IN (?)',
    username(req), videos);

...which runs without error, but gave me no matches when I should have gotten a few. What works is this:
  await db.all(`SELECT video, offset, watched FROM watched WHERE user = ? AND video IN ('${videos.join("','")}')`,
    username(req));

...but that's hardly a "best practices" way to do this, even though I do filter the content of the array to prevent SQL injection.
Is there a proper way to pass an array value that I haven't found yet?

What is video in your sqlite schema, and what is videos on the JS side? Because IN requires that the value and list of values are compatible types of course. 1 IN [1,2,3], or "cake" IN ["cat", "cake", "carrot"].

@Mike, it's a string field, specifically a hexadecimal hash code identifying particular videos.

Don't tell "me": show everyone by putting that in your post. That's important information that's currently missing. (And after doing that, of course, prove that this is what happens by showing this with a [MRE])

@Mike, OK, I updated the post. I had thought that the way I was doing the join, to wrap all of the values in videos in single quotes with commas in between, made that clear, however.

Not even slightly: if you don't show what's actually in videos, that join might just be the string[[object Object], [object Object]], so prove there is a problem with an MRE (not just to us, but far more to yourself. It's why MRE are so valuable: forcing yourself to make one more often than not makes you go "omg of course, it was [...]" and then you don't even need SO's help anymore)

(on that note, of course, remember to turn on db trace debugging so you see what the actual SQL statement is that's getting fired off, to see if it's different from expectations)

I don't think this library supports using a single placeholder for a list value, like node-mysql does. So you need to construct the (?, ?, ...) list dynamically, and provide all the values using a spread argument.
placeholders = Array(videos.length).fill('?').join(',');
await db.all(`
    SELECT video, offset, watched 
    FROM watched 
    WHERE user = ? AND video IN (${placeholders})`,
    username(req), ...videos);


Thanks! That's a good, less sloppy way to do this. If you're correct that the library simply doesn't provide a way to pass an array to a single placeholder, I'll come back and mark this as THE answer.

I searched the documentation of both the regular and promised versions of the library, and couldn't find any mention of using a placeholder with IN.

SQLite does not support binding an array like that.
An alternative approach to @Barmar's answer that I've used with arrays of size 10k+ items in production is to use json_each and pass the data as a JSON string:
await db.all(
  "SELECT video, offset, watched FROM watched WHERE user = ? AND video IN (SELECT value from json_each(?))",
  username(req),
  JSON.stringify(videos),
);


Also note that SQLite has a limit on the number of variables you can bind (~32k by default) while the json_each method works well for millions of elements. The following script, which passes 10 million integers to sqlite, executed with Bun.js, takes a bit over 1 second to execute for me:
import { Database } from "bun:sqlite";

const db = new Database(":memory:");

console.log(
  db
    .query(
      "select x from (select value as x from json_each(?)) where x % 1000000 == 0"
    )
    .all(JSON.stringify(Array.from({ length: 10_000_000 }, (_, i) => i)))
);


Nice alternative!
